# Android layout with dynamically generated picture

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, graphic

I know it's possible to have a layout with mixture of non graphic elements (like Buttons) and graphic elements (Images), but is there a way of having a layout that combines non graphic elements with graphic elements dynamically created/changed?

For example: I want to have a layout with some buttons and one picture (Image), but the picture is to be a graph that is going to be dynamically generated, so I need to be able to paint on the picture. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create cutom view and add in your layout, refer this http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: I was hoping to get a simple example, let's say: a view with a button (that does nothing) and an empty ImageView (can be white rectangle - doesn't matter) with let's say black line drawn from the program.